# LinearState with OneToMany mappings

Tags: corda

I have a state which derives from LinearState and QueryableState. The state has a OneToMany mapping with one of the attributes in the sate. Adding a OneToMany marks the key with a Unique constraint.

When i try to consume and create a new such state (keeping linearId same), this Unique key is violated as corda stores all consumed & unconsumed states in the same table.

How can this be modelled in corda?

Answer (score 1):

You could use JoinColumns with output_index and transaction_id as shown below. These values will always be different since any update will require a new transaction.

```
@JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "output_index", referencedColumnName = "output_index"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "transaction_id", referencedColumnName = "transaction_id"),
})
```

Here is a blog explaining hierarchical relationships in Corda.

https://medium.com/corda/implementing-hierarchical-relationship-with-corda-queryablestate-15049fed5934